# Notepad++ How put window on the right side?

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ as my IDE.
And I meet a problem when I using the function list window.

Normally I would put the function list on the right side,
the project explorer window is on the left side.
If I put the function list window on the left side,
it will merge up into one window with several tag.
This is not going to very comfortable when I am coding.

Recently, I push the wrong button in the function list window,
and it left the right side and become the individual window.
I try to jack it to right side again, 
but it take the upper area as upper window.

So now, I can only leave it into individual window form near the right side. 
It still work, but it is wired.....
I don't know how to put it in the right side again.
[image]

Comment: As with all other floating windows apps, it takes a few tries: grab the function list window, say by left- clicking its tittlebar with the mouse. Keep the mouse button pressed and drag the window to the side of notepad++ frame you want to attach to. When the mouse cursor (still keeping pressed, still dragging the function list window) come close to that side, the function list window will attach to the side (it suddenly snaps there when within 10 pixels vicinity)

Comment: @LarsFischer Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As with all other floating windows apps, it takes a few tries:

- grab the function list window, say by left- clicking its tittlebar with the mouse.
- Keep the mouse button pressed and
- drag the window to the side of notepad++ frame you want to attach to. * When the mouse cursor (still keeping pressed, still dragging the function list window) comes close to that side, the function list window will attach to the side (it suddenly snaps there when within 10 pixels vicinity)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was not able to attach to npp window to the right. I kept hovering over the screen, it would attach to the top but not to the right. Then I opened another view (view-> function List) which showed up on right. After that when I hovered the npp window to right, it attached immediately.
Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click Document map button. i highlighted the logo in pinned picture.]

First click Document map button. Right side document manager was opened .Then next go Toolbar click plugins ->NppFTP->showNppFTP window. The window was created in your right side.You can setup and use the NppFTP Connection